# Blackborders on video edited on kdenlive (only on Phone not in Laptop)

Tags: kdenlive

I edited a video using Kdenlive in my laptop. I played the video. It was fine .So I transferred it to my Phone. But when i played the video on my phone, it has a 1cm thick black border.

Why is this happening?

And why only on phone?

Can someone please suggest a fix for this?

Comment: Is the aspect ratio of your laptop is different from the one on your phone? If so, then you probably see pillarboxing or letterboxing. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pillarbox or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letterboxing_(filming)

Comment: What media player are you using on your phone? Some players, like VLC IIRC, have the option to either play video in actual resolution or scaled to fit the screen. On desktop for interface reasons this doesn't typically happen but on mobile you could be that your phone app is showing at actual resolution instead of at actual ratio (scaled up to fill the screen)